# Adding a column to an excel sheet table based on if else condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to add a column named "Roles".

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngX, "Roles") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Roles column Already present"
Else
     ESheet.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight,CopyOrigin:=xlFormatLeftOrAbove
     ESheet.Range("C1").Value = "Roles"
     LastRow1=ESheet.Range("A", & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     ESheet.Range("C2:C", & LastRow1).Formula="VLOOKUP(B2, Roles!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
End IF
```

I am trying this code, There is a Roles sheet which I am referring for vlookup and adding new column named "Roles" in new tab "Titles". If column is already there, it shows msgbox but changes Vlookup values -- `vlookup(B2, #Ref!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

Basically i want to remove this vlookup error so that it keeps referring Roles tab

Comment: Is the column having "Roles" header always the third one?

Comment: Anyhow, my code works for that situation, too. It would solve the problem even if the column would not be the third one...

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the job.

```
Const Cap As String = "Roles"
Const Clm As Long = 3

With ESheet.Columns(Clm)
    If .Cells(1).Value <> Cap Then
        .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Cells(1).Offset(0, -1).Value = Cap
    End If
End With
```

It will check if the caption of columns(Clm) - where 3 = "C" - is `Cap` (here "Roles"). If it isn't a blank column will be inserted and given that name.

I took note that you address the worksheet by its `CodeName`. Few people here do although its efficient and usually preferable. If you did so by accident or error note the alternation, `Worksheets("ESheet")` which addresses the same sheet by its tab name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub ConditInsertColumn()
  Dim ESheet As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, rngRol As Range
  'Set ESheet = ActiveSheet 'use here your definition or skip it
  lastCol = ESheet.Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).column
   Set rngRol = ESheet.Range(ESheet.Cells(1, 1), ESheet.Cells(1, lastCol)).Find("Roles")
    If rngRol Is Nothing Then
        ESheet.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatLeftOrAbove
        ESheet.Range("C1").value = "Roles"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count if you got any header in row 1 with value `Roles`. If the count is 0, add the column, else it means the column already exists, so do nothing

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ESheet.Rows("1:1"), "Roles") = 0 Then
    ESheet.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatLeftOrAbove
    ESheet.Range("C1").Value = "Roles"
End If
```

Comment: This condition works but it changes my Vlookup formula. Please see my edited code above. Vlookup throws error.

Comment: @NipenMahajan That's a different question. Anyways, why inserting a column would make your Vlookup fail?